# CSS: in this flex container, how to make the <li> move to the empty space automatically

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

[image: Calendar screenshot that helps explain my question]

In this calendar, after date 6, I added a new

to contain the "upcoming events" image, which should take 2 columns of height. Ideally the date 8 should move below 6, and 9 below 7 to fill up the space, but it is not doing so.

Appreciate any of your help and advice!

```css
.event_calendar ul {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

.event_calendar .days {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.event_calendar li {
  display: flex;
  color: #333;
  width: calc(100% / 5);
}

.event_calendar .days li {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

.days li::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: translate(0%, -30%);
}

.days li.event_date::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background: #f2f2f2;
  background-image: url('https://st2.depositphotos.com/1635204/7654/i/450/depositphotos_76549817-stock-photo-word-events-on-colorful-wooden.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: translate(0%, -30%);
}

.days li.upcoming_event_preview {
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

.days li.upcoming_event_preview::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-image: url('https://clipart-library.com/img1/1038152.png');
  background-size: contain;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: translate(0%, -10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="event_calendar">
  <ul class="days">
    <li class="event_date"> 1 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 2 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 3 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 4 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 5 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 6 </li>
    <li class="upcoming_event_preview"></li>
    <li class="event_date"> 7 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 8 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 9 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 10 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 11</li>
    <li class="event_date"> 12 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried to play around with the flexbox, but nothing worked so far. (I do not want to make any the date stretch and fill by doing `flex: 1` )

Comment: Welcome! That's not how the flexbox model works. You want to use CSS grid here. Flexbox works on an X and Y axis without allowing the placement of elements inside of specific columns and rows. If you use `grid` you can easily place the image within a specific column/row with the date blocks around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `flexbox` won't get you what here, here's an example using `display: grid`;

I've commented the CSS.

**NOTE**: I did use the original specific `px` values for the columns that were set in the original question, e.g., 100px. I would recommend changing these to percent values or something that would respond as browser size changes.

```css
.event_calendar ul {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: grid; /* GRID */
  list-style: none;
  color: #000000;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px); /* SET THE COLUMNS - 5, repeats 100px */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 25%); /* SET 4 ROWS, EQUAL HEIGHT */
  grid-gap: 10px; /* USE GAP INSTEAD OF MARGIN */
  text-align: center;
}

.event_calendar .days {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.event_calendar li {
  display: flex;
  color: #333;
 }

.event_calendar .days li {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

.days li::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: translate(0%, -30%);
}

.days li.event_date::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background: #f2f2f2;
  background-image: url('https://st2.depositphotos.com/1635204/7654/i/450/depositphotos_76549817-stock-photo-word-events-on-colorful-wooden.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: translate(0%, -30%);
}

.days li.upcoming_event_preview {
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  grid-column: 2/span 3; /* POSITION THE IMAGE LI IN THE 2ND COLUMN AND MAKE IT SPAN 3 COLUMNS TOTAL */
  grid-row: 2/span 2; /* POSITION THE IMAGE LI IN THE 2ND ROW AND MAKE IT SPAN 2 ROWS TOTAL */
}

.days li.upcoming_event_preview::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  /* a little house keeping for the image to be in the middle of the li element */
  background-image: url('https://clipart-library.com/img1/1038152.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(0%, -10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="event_calendar">
  <ul class="days">
    <li class="event_date"> 1 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 2 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 3 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 4 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 5 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 6 </li>
    <li class="upcoming_event_preview"></li>
    <li class="event_date"> 7 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 8 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 9 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 10 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 11</li>
    <li class="event_date"> 12 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Responsive**

```css
.event_calendar ul {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: grid;
  /* GRID */
  list-style: none;
  color: #000000;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, calc(20% - 10px));
  /* SET THE COLUMNS - 5, repeats 20% - 10px to account for the gap */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 25%);
  /* SET 4 ROWS, EQUAL HEIGHT */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  /* USE GAP INSTEAD OF MARGIN */
  text-align: center;
}

.event_calendar .days {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.event_calendar li {
  display: flex;
  color: #333;
}

.event_calendar .days li {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

.days li::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: translate(0%, -30%);
}

.days li.event_date::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background: #f2f2f2;
  background-image: url('https://st2.depositphotos.com/1635204/7654/i/450/depositphotos_76549817-stock-photo-word-events-on-colorful-wooden.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.days li.upcoming_event_preview {
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  grid-column: 2/span 3;
  /* POSITION THE IMAGE LI IN THE 2ND COLUMN AND MAKE IT SPAN 3 COLUMNS TOTAL */
  grid-row: 2/span 2;
  /* POSITION THE IMAGE LI IN THE 2ND ROW AND MAKE IT SPAN 2 ROWS TOTAL */
}

.days li.upcoming_event_preview::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  /* a little house keeping for the image to be in the middle of the li element */
  background-image: url('https://clipart-library.com/img1/1038152.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(0%, -10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="event_calendar">
  <ul class="days">
    <li class="event_date"> 1 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 2 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 3 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 4 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 5 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 6 </li>
    <li class="upcoming_event_preview"></li>
    <li class="event_date"> 7 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 8 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 9 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 10 </li>
    <li class="event_date"> 11</li>
    <li class="event_date"> 12 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! That fixed my problem perfectly! I'll go learn more about grid for sure :D
Have a wonderful weekend!